# How do I combine if and button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when you press the button, it counts down from 33. and I want repeat value 33 after 0 How do I with 'if'?

```js
export default class App extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
  }
  harrik = {
    number : 33
  };
  onPressDecrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      number: --this.harrik.number,

      
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onPressDecrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      number: --this.harrik.number,
    });
    if(this.harrik.number === 0) { 
       this.harrik.number = 33; 
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem with it

Answer (score 0):

Using the ternary operator `?:` is the best approach,
I'm using the callback, which setState accepts as the second parameter, then returns the object to change the state.

```
onPressDecrease = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => 
     ({ number: prevState.number === 0 ? 33 : --prevState.number })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want values to roll over after a certain point, your best bet is usually a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```js
// modulo function using JavaScript's `%` (remainder) operator
const modulo = (num, modulus) => ((num % modulus) + modulus) % modulus

modulo(-1, 33) // 32
modulo(0, 33) // 0
modulo(1, 33) // 1
// ...
modulo(32, 33) // 32
modulo(33, 33) // 0
modulo(34, 33) // 1
```